# Error adding VectorAssembler to Spark ML Pipeline

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Trying to add VectorAssembler to the GBT pipeline example and get an error the pipeline cannot find the features field. I'm bringing in a sample file instead of a libsvm so I needed to transform the feature set set.

Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist.

```
 val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("data/training_example.csv")

val sampleDF = df.sample(false,0.05,987897L)

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("val1","val2","val3",...,"valN"))
  .setOutputCol("features")

val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("label")
  .setOutputCol("indexedLabel")
  .fit(sampleDF)

val featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer()
  .setInputCol("features")
  .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures")
  .setMaxCategories(4)
  .fit(sampleDF)

val Array(trainingData, testData) = sampleDF.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))

val gbt = new GBTClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
  .setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures")
  .setMaxIter(3)
  .setMaxDepth(5)

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(assembler,labelIndexer,featureIndexer,gbt))

val model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)

val predictions = model.transform(testData)

predictions.show(10)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Basic problem:**

Why you're calling fit() in featureIndexer?

If you call fit(sampleDF), VectorIndexer will search for features column in sampleDF, but this dataset doesn't have such column.

Pipeline's fit() will call all transformator and estimators, so call fit on assembler, then pass the result to fit of labelIndexer and pass previous step result to fit of featureIndexer.

DataFrame that will be used in featureIndexer.fit() called inside Pipeline will have all columns generated by previous transformers.

In your code sampleDF doesn't have features column, however, during Pipeline fit() this column will be added by assembler

Comment: To answer your question, I am following the Spark documentation. Possibly my first mistake.  That said, this makes complete sense. I'm trying it now.

Comment: [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/ml-classification-regression.html#gradient-boosted-tree-classifier)

Comment: That's weird because removing the fit seemed to work just fine.

Comment: @JimHendricks Please see my update - I did one huge mistake, VectorIndexer is a estimator and must be trained. Documentation tells the truth, solution must be other than mentioned before

Comment: I dug into the scaladocs and you're right. It is an estimator. I'm re-running with the change above. I'll update when I see the results.

Comment: @JimHendricks WOW, Spark is more clever than I thought. Pipeline fit() recognizes estimators and trains them. I didn't know it, but I've just seen it in code. Spark developers, you are doing very good job :D Sorry for confusing you. I've again updated my answer, maybe now all possibilities are clearly explained

Comment: Yeah, that's a good thing since that last change (.fit(assembler.transform(sampleDF))) did not work. However, calling fit on the pipeline does indeed work.

Comment: @JimHendricks documentation probably should be updated - I'll look on it later. Well, I've tried to help and I've learn new things, sorry that I did a mistake previously

Comment: Thanks, actually that did help. I've learned more about pipelines in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation sample has features column from the beginning.

```
val data = sqlContext.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")
```

You must fit a DF having features column.So transform your original DF with VectorAssembler and give it as input.